# Calling a method while shifting tab - angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call a method while tab shifting but facing bit confuse. I am using 'click' but this is working while click of any thing under that tab. Here my intention is while shifting tab, method supposed to be click.
If any one have idea please help me.

This is my  template class:

```html
<tabs>
<tab heading="It's First tab" (click)="firstTab()">
       First tab content
</tab>   
<tab heading="It's Second tab" (click)="secondTab()">
       second tab content
</tab>   
<tab heading="It's Third tab" (click)="thirdTab()">
     third tab content
</tab>     
</tabs>
```

Comment: You need a way to place a function on the tab heading, not the tab itself.

Comment: What library are you using to make the tabs?

Comment: @fredrik carbon libraries I'm using..How can we place all functions in tab heading..Based on tab selection only that particular function should call right..

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library. You will need to read the documentation unless someone else knows. Though since you have not added all this information in the question (and it's tags) it's unlikely that they will find it. Also, since you only gave angular and typescript as tag I first assumed that you were using angular's built in tab system...

Comment: @fredrik Leave about the design system, Basically I'm learner..so what is the normal way to call method while tab shifting I'm looking. Any how thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe I have a solution to your problem. Could you check for me, from a browsers console, if all tabs headers have a class in common that no other tag's using?

Comment: @FedericoGalfione Yes no other tag's are using..but displaying each tab contains some conditions. So based on conditions tabs will display.

Comment: Sorry probably I was not clear. I was talking about tabs headers (probably some divs) inside tab components template. You could see them from the browser console. I need to know if there are any classes inside those divs (the ones you really click on)

Comment: @FedericoGalfione Yes you are correct, under divs I'm calling suppurate component.  ex:<tabs>
<tab heading="It's First tab" (click)="firstTab()">
       <app-first-component></app-first-component>
</tab> 
</tabs>

Comment: Could you share the link of the library you’re using for the tabs component? Probably in this way I can do rapid test

Comment: @FedericoGalfione https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/tabs/code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the component [documentation](https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-angular/blob/master/src/tabs/tab.component.ts) there is an EventEmitter called `selected` that is emit every time the tab is selected.
So try to change your code with something like this:

```html
<tabs>
    <tab heading="It's First tab" (selected)="firstTab()">
        First tab content
    </tab>   
    <tab heading="It's Second tab" (selected)="secondTab()">
        second tab content
    </tab>   
    <tab heading="It's Third tab" (selected)="thirdTab()">
        third tab content
    </tab>     
</tabs>
```